# In Swift, How to add Badges on UIImageView in TableViewCell in TableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios9.3

I am developing a social networking site where I have a TableView with multiple cells(rows), in each cell I have a "comment" and "like" Imageview, so whenever update comes from the server I have to increment the number of "comment" and "like" through badges. So how to add badges on UIImageView in TableViewCell in Swift

Answer (score 5):

You can **add Badge on UIImageView** this way

```
func drawImageView(mainImage: UIImage, withBadge badge: UIImage) -> UIImage
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(mainImage.size, false, 0.0)
    mainImage.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, mainImage.size.width, mainImage.size.height))
    badge.drawInRect(CGRectMake(mainImage.size.width - badge.size.width, 0, badge.size.width, badge.size.height))

    let resultImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return resultImage
}
```

and then use this function

```
    let mainImage = UIImage(named: "main_image_name_here")
    let badgeImage = UIImage(named: "badge_icon_name_here")
    let myBadgedImage: UIImage = drawImageView(mainImage!, withBadge: badgeImage!)
    myImageView.image = myBadgedImage//set Image on ImageView
```

Answer (score 2):

check out this [MIBadgeButton-Swift](https://github.com/mustafaibrahim989/MIBadgeButton-Swift)

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

RDC's answer in SWIFT 3

```
func drawImageView(mainImage: UIImage, withBadge badge: UIImage) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(mainImage.size, false, 0.0)
    mainImage.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: mainImage.size.width, height: mainImage.size.height))
    badge.draw(in: CGRect(x: mainImage.size.width - badge.size.width, y: 0, width: badge.size.width, height: badge.size.height))

    let resultImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return resultImage
}
```